# Elasticsearch: is possible to write a case sensitive query?

Tags: full-text-search, elasticsearch, case-sensitive

Some terms in the query must be case insensitive, but some others must be case sensitive. The idea is, for example, to produce a query to all docs with "Mr. Brown", but not the brown houses.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can create a [custom analyzer](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) which does not include the [lowercase filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-lowercase-tokenfilter.html). In that case you could use a simple match query and it would take into account the case sensitivity.

Comment: Unfortunately, that means that if you want to support both case-sensitive and case-insensitive, you'll need duplicate copies of the data in the indx